# How to change this txt to a CSV in JAVA

Tags: java, eclipse, csv, ide

The txt file attached has different spaces within it, making it harder to change to CSV format within java using eclipse IDE, I tried splitting it but had no luck, the txt file has weather data ranging from 1908 through to 2013, each set of data is in the following format - yyyy  mm   tmax    tmin      af    rain     sun

Opening it in excel shows how it should look, though I will need to use the txt file within the program and split it into arrays eventually, so I cannot simply convert it using excel, I don't know how to deal with the different spacing within the document otherwise I would be fine.

Thanks in advance for anybody's help :)

link to the files -https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4YNBcGEuF3hT3JsLURIZUdTdFE

note you will need to download the file to see it how I will receive the files :)

below is a sample of the text file

```
1908   1    5.0    -1.4      21     ---    29.7
1908   2    7.3     1.9       8     ---    71.9
1908   3    6.2     0.3      13     ---   101.4
1908   4    8.6     2.1       5     ---   128.6
1908   5   15.8     7.7       0     ---   180.4
1908   6   17.7     8.7       0     ---   196.9
1908   7   18.9    11.0       0     ---   196.1
1908   8   17.5     9.7       0     ---   187.2
1908   9   16.3     8.4       0     ---    99.5
1908  10   14.6     8.0       0     ---    56.1
1908  11    9.6     3.4       6     ---    28.4
1908  12    5.8     0.0      13     ---    10.3
1909   1    5.0     0.1      11     ---    35.6
1909   2    5.5    -0.3      18     ---    49.9
1909   3    5.6    -0.3      17     ---    58.7
1909   4   12.2     3.3       3     ---   188.9
1909   5   14.7     4.8       2     ---   216.8
1909   6   15.0     7.5       0     ---   139.5
1909   7   17.3    10.8       0     ---   151.2
1909   8   18.8    10.7       0     ---   167.5
1909   9   14.5     8.1       0     ---    74.4
1909  10   12.9     6.9       3     ---   101.5
1909  11    7.5     1.7      10     ---    60.8
1909  12    5.3     0.4      10     ---    31.5
1910   1    5.2    -0.5      13     ---    43.4
1910   2    7.0     1.5       7     ---    74.3
1910   3    9.1     2.2       4     ---   123.1
1910   4    9.8     2.4       4     ---   118.2
1910   5   14.3     6.0       0     ---   185.8
1910   6   17.7     9.6       0     ---   163.4
1910   7   17.0     9.8       0     ---   169.7
1910   8   18.0    11.8       0     ---   133.8
1910   9   15.0     8.5       0     ---   106.1
1910  10   12.6     7.3       0     ---    69.7
1910  11    5.5    -0.4      17     ---    66.0
1910  12    8.0     3.6       3     ---    24.0
1911   1    5.8     1.8       6    33.0    23.5
1911   2    6.9     1.3       8    91.7    65.8
1911   3    6.4     1.9       2    25.1    83.6
1911   4   10.0     3.9       3    26.4   128.3
1911   5   16.3     7.9       0    24.6   192.3
1911   6   17.8     9.0       0    84.3   225.3
1911   7   22.2    11.7       0     4.9   280.6
1911   8   21.6    12.5       0    51.8   204.8
1911   9   17.3     8.6       0    74.5   171.2
1911  10   11.4     5.6       1    87.3    57.6
1911  11    7.9     3.2       4    90.1    59.3
1911  12    8.2     3.3       0   119.1    18.4
1912   1    4.8     0.1      11   140.0    15.4
1912   2    6.6     1.3       7    57.3    48.1
1912   3    9.0     3.5       3   121.7    71.7
1912   4   12.4     3.4       5    15.5   184.9
1912   5   14.9     6.6       0    75.4   135.4
1912   6   16.7     9.9       0   156.7   122.9
1912   7   18.3    11.7       0    92.1   107.4
1912   8   15.1     9.2       0   144.0    87.0
1912   9   13.7     7.7       0    41.2   102.0
1912  10   11.6     4.2       1    85.1    71.3
1912  11    8.3     3.8       4    63.9    39.5
1912  12    8.9     2.4       5   107.1    15.4
1913   1    5.4     1.1      12   108.7     7.2
1913   2    7.2     1.2       8    32.1    40.8
1913   3    8.3     2.1       3   112.6    93.8
1913   4   10.6     3.8       3    90.9    96.4
1913   5   14.7     6.8       0    65.8   148.5
1913   6   17.4     9.5       0    40.9   181.8
1913   7   17.5    10.4       0    18.3   131.2
1913   8   18.5    10.1       0    40.7   142.4
1913   9   16.9    10.3       0    42.7   109.9
1913  10   12.7     7.3       1    65.9    66.3
1913  11   10.1     5.1       0    82.4    35.8
1913  12    6.8     2.3       7    68.6    11.9
1914   1    6.0     0.7      10    59.5    17.4
1914   2    9.5     3.5       2    68.4    50.3
```

Comment: What do you mean? Before reading it, can't you replace all spaces with an empty string ""?

Comment: Many of the users that might be willing to help you are hesitant to click any links in questions. You might consider editing the question to include a sample of the data in-line in your question.

Comment: Also, your question (and the answers) have the potential to last forever. Is that link still going to be good in five or ten years?

Comment: no problem, will refrain from doing so in future posts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `java.util.Scanner` to read the lines of the text file. It doesn't matter that there are different numbers of white spaces between the data. The Scanner will handle this automatically.

Comment: How could I then take the separate values and store them in arrays? I can read the file, just unsure how to separate them now

Comment: Again, using the Scanner. Use `String dataToAddToArray = <instantiated scanner object here>.next();` in a loop. If you don't have any luck just comment back tomorrow and I will edit my answer to show you how I would do it.